# Sorted list using knockout.js with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am building a sorted list using knockout.js. I have a version working with a simple observable array but how can I make it work with my json data and using the mapping plugin?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/x66Ts/

```
        // Here is my json data
        var viewModel;
        $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/name/Stuart', function (data) {
            viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });

// Here is my working version of the simple observable array. How can it work using json data and the mapping plugin?
var ListSortModel = function () {

  // my items
    this.allItems = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Denise' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Bert' }
    ]); 

    // sorter
    this.sortItems = function() {
        this.allItems(this.allItems().sort(function(a, b) { return a.name > b.name;}));
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ListSortModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` element is bound to `allItems` array of view model. But when you are mapping results, you just have single object with observable property `name`. There is no `allItems` property. So, you will simply receive an error:

> Error: Unable to parse bindings. 
>   Message: ReferenceError: allItems is not defined; 
>   Bindings value: foreach: allItems

Another problem is that you get single item `{"name": "Stuart"}` in response (not array of items). You can't just assign that item to view model's `allItems` property. You need to add that item to view model items:

```
var viewModel = new ListSortModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/name/Stuart', function (data) {
    var item = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); // make it observable
    viewModel.allItems.push(item); // add to view model items
});
```

Comment: I would like to still use the mapping plugin to map the data from json.